# prevent user change view

Tags: list-view

There was a question in my mind that how is possible to create a list or a document or form library, then create some views in it, but limit simple users to see only one view. and so some specific users ( for example managers ) see more than one view ?

please step by step explain for me

thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

my problem solved with add solution to sitecollection
see this link http://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/
it is very good

Comment: I've been looking for something like this for months, can't wait to test it out! +1 for continuing your research even after asking.